# Безопасно ли таким образом создавать динамический массив?

Tags: c++, массивы, динамические-массивы

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int **createArray(int rows, int cols) {
    int **arr = new int*[rows];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) 
        arr[i] = new int[cols];
    return arr;
}
void setArray(int **arr, int rows, int cols) {
    srand(time(0));
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = 1 + rand() % 10;
        }
    }
}
void printArray(int **arr, int rows, int cols) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            cout << setw(3) << left << arr[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    int rows, cols;
    cout << "Введите кол-во строк: ";
    cin >> rows;
    cout << "Введите кол-во столбцов: ";
    cin >> cols;

    int **arr = createArray(rows, cols);

    setArray(arr, rows, cols);
    printArray(arr, rows, cols);

    _getch();
    return 0;

}
```

Безопасно ли (с точки зрения утечки памяти) использовать функцию createArray?

Comment: Если вы не забудете по окончании работы освободить всю выделенную в функции память. Но у вас же С++ - почему бы не воспользоваться `vector<vector<...>>`?

Comment: "Если вы не забудете по окончании работы освободить всю выделенную в функции память" - в main'е?

Comment: Там, где она больше не нужна :) В частности, в `main`.

Comment: @Harry понятно, спасибо :)